# AttributeError: type object 'DataFrame' has no attribute 'read_csv'

Tags: python, visualization, pandas, csv

I'm trying to create some charts using Python. I've this dataset in a CSV file:

```
Banana  Water   Rice
Rice    Water
Bread   Banana  Juice
```

And I've this code:

```
 import numpy as np
 from pandas import DataFrame
 import matplotlib
 matplotlib.use('agg') # Write figure to disk instead of displaying (for Windows Subsystem for Linux)
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
 data = DataFrame.read_csv("test.csv", index_col=1, skiprows=1).T.to_dict()
```

But when I execute the code I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'DataFrame' has no attribute 'read_csv'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`read_csv()` is not available on DataFrame. to read csvs using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("file_name")
```

If you check `type(data)`, it will be pandas DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

For reading data from csv you can use `pd.read_csv` or `pd.read_table`.
Example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("file_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

`pd.read_csv` is used to read a csv file, you are trying to make a dictionary into a dataframe, use `pd.DataFrame()` function for this.